# Why did I get different answers in vscode?

Tags: c, algorithm

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{
    int n = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int power = 1; power <= n; power++)
    {
        printf("%d %s ", (int)pow(10, power) - 1, power == n ? "=" : "+");
        sum += (int)pow(10, power) - 1;
    }
    printf ("%d", sum);
    return 0;    
}
```

Output in Vs Code with gcc:

```
Enter a number: 5
9 + 98 + 999 + 9998 + 99999 = 111103
```

Output in online compilers:

```
Enter a number: 5
9 + 99 + 999 + 9999 + 99999 = 111105
```

My question: Why? is this happening?

Comment: [The classic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) . Also you may get different answers with the same compiler and different optimization settings.

Comment: With these kinds of questions please be maximally specific when it comes to compiler versions. “online compiler” isn’t a good description, and nor is “VS code with gcc” enough. What version? What options?

Comment: Several issues: First, the code is always rounding down which can be an issue if pow result is slightly lower than the closed integer. Second, it does not check the input. It is vulnerable to overflow. Third: The sum accumulates the rounding errors.

Comment: I now tested the code above with gcc 9.3, https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler and visual c version 19.16.27043. None of them showed the above behaviour. Did you use some outdated compiler version? Which runtime/sdk version did you use (if you used vc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly an issue with `pow` and its implementation, perhaps due to different platform or compilers.

Instead of using `pow` which relies on floating point arithmetic and leads to compounding rounding errors (and possibly contains bugs), why not use simple multiplication? If you start the loop with `10`, then you could multiply that by `10` each iteration to get the result you want.

Perhaps something like this:

```
unsigned sum = 0;
for (unsigned power = 0, value = 10; power < n; ++power, value *= 10)
{
    sum += value - 1;
}
```

<sub>[Printing left out]</sub>

Comment: @KonradRudolph: IEEE 754 does not fully constrain the results of `pow` and other routines. So this is not a conformance issue. Also, C implementations commonly do not conform to IEEE 754.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Clearly I’m wrong since GCC and clang disagree on something so fundamental, but I fail to see how `pow` on integer powers of 10 can give different answers without this being a glaring bug. Just because IEEE-754 doesn’t “fully” constrain these functions doesn’t give implementations license to do whatever they want. The fact that this gives wrong results should be very unexpected.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Nonetheless, it is incorrect to characterize it as a floating-point issue. Nothing about floating-point precludes returning correct results in this case. Microsoft’s `pow` returns incorrect results even though correct results are possible in this case and are returned by other implementations. When an integer routine returns an incorrect result, we do not characterize it as an integer error.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Please show us how you would implement `pow` to return correct results in all cases where an exact result is possible.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am *not* saying this is possible. I am saying that *even if* this is impossible, `pow` shouldn’t make errors willy-nilly. And in particular integer powers of 10 within the range of the underlying type should probably work (if for no other reason than that they crop up fairly frequently in actual usage, e.g. to label log-scaled graphs). In fact, clang does some really weird stuff here: https://godbolt.org/z/reKM57

Comment: @KonradRudolph: As I wrote, show us how you would implement `pow` to return correct results in all cases where an exact result is possible. Once you try, even briefly, you will see that `pow` is not making errors “willy-nilly.” There are reasons for it, and you will understand better once you have the knowledge gained by trying. On the other hand, I criticize Microsoft’s implementation not because it makes errors “willy-nilly,” but because, even though implementing `pow` with the necessary quality is hard, Microsoft should have invested the required effort (earlier than it did).

Comment: Looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754 it seems there are both binary as well as decimal representations covered by the standard. If someone asked me i had answered without thinking that c doubles are implemented using the former. Now i've written a test program which outputs the pow result to 20 digits and got no digits beside zero after the point. So now i'm pretty sure gcc implemented it's doubles on a base of 10 in contrast to my expectation. May it be that other compilers still use the binary representation which could probably result in the differences shown in the question?

Comment: I mean that the result of assigning a double to an integer may be dependent on the direction of approach to the final calculation value. If one approaches from the top the integer would be the expected one. If one approaches from bottom, the integer would be one less than expected. Of course, this holds only if the double is represented in binary form, else powers of ten had an exact representation.

Comment: @pqans “So now i'm pretty sure gcc implemented it's doubles on a base of 10” — No, that isn’t the case unless you run on a very obscure piece of hardware (and I don’t think GCC would support that). All modern commodity hardware implements base 2 doubles in the machine, and GCC uses the machine representation when translating C++ code.

Comment: Sorry, i was completely mistaken. The powers of ten considered here are exactly representable in the binary system. E.g. `1e+09 = 0.931323 * 2^30`.  That's why the pow function should not exhibit rounding errors when calculating powers of ten and that's why the output of Vs Code with gcc is indeed inherently faulty.

Answer (score 2):

I just use the function "round" which returns the integer rounding closest to the value specified in parameter

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{
    int n = 0;
    int sum=0;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int power = 1; power <= n; power++)
    {
        sum += (int)round (pow(10, power)) - 1;
    }
    printf ("%d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesnt really answer the question as to why it happens, but then neither does the (hastily) accepted answer. However this answer better targets where the issue arises when compared to the accepted answers approach of offering totally different code.